# jqGrid setting the default value for a text field on adding

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

There is a requirement in jqGrid, where i need to add a default value for a text field when the new row is added.

Example.

For a field in a row, 1000 is set as default, when each new record is added every time.

Is there any way to achieve it.

Comment: I tried with this editoptions: {defaultValue:'aValue'}

Comment: No i do not have the edit url

Comment: I got the answer from robin herbots. He said to update the js file to the latest version. I tested and it is working fine.